# Unity Dependency Injection from usercontrol viewmodel to customUsercontrol Viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container

I have a `UserControl` which is bound to a `viewmodel`. The `viewmodel` has parameters in the constructor which is done via dependency injection. The dependency injection is working fine up to this point.

And then I have a `CustomUserControl` which is Used in my `UserControl1View`.
How do I get the Dependency injection working in my `CustomUserControl`?

I am new to dependency injection and did some research, but can't seem to get it working. I get an error on

```
public partial class UserControl1View : UserControl, IView {
    public UserControl1View( ) {
        InitializeComponent( );
    }
}
```

This is the error:
[image]

Here is the example of the code.

**UserControl**:

```
public partial class UserControl1View : UserControl, IView {
    public UserControl1View( ) {
        InitializeComponent( );
    }
}
```

**UserControlViewModel**:

```
public class UserControl1ViewModel 
{
    private readonly ISomeDataService dataService;
    public UserControl1ViewModel (ISomeDataService dataservice, IUnityContainer container ) 
    {
       //Please note that the Dependency injection still works in this class, to much to explain the whole structure.   
       this.dataService = dataservice;
       container.RegisterType( typeof( IView ), typeof( CustomUserControlView ) ); 
       var view = container.Resolve<CustomUserControlView>( );
    }
```

**XAML**:

```
<uc:CustomUserControlView/>
```

---

**CustomUserControl**:

```
public partial class CustomUserControlView : UserControl, IView 
{
    public CustomUserControlView(IUnityContainer container) 
    {
        container.RegisterType( typeof( IViewModel ), typeof( CustomControlViewModel ) );
        var viewModel = container.Resolve<CustomControlViewModel>( );
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent( );
    }
}
```

**CustomUserControlViewModel**:

```
public partial class CustomUserControlViewModel : UserControl, IView 
{
   private readonly ISomeDataService dataService;
   public CustomUserControlViewModel(ISomeDataService dataservice) 
   {
      var data = dataService.GetsomeCollection()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution is simple. Don't use DI/IoC container to inject controls. It's not going to work and was never supposed to work.

User controls (in contrast to views) are meant to be self-contained and work out of the box with other applications or the IDE designer w/o requiring a container. Otherwise they just won't work well with the designer, as the Xaml designer has no concept of DI/IoC and won't know how to resolve/instantiate a certain class and requires an parameterless constructor. Also a "user control" doesn't split it's logic into a ViewModel.

A view on other side is just an UI template without code. It also derives from `Windows` or `UserControl` class, but has no logic of it's own and is not reusable. A view is always very specific for a special ViewModel and ViewModels are very specific to **one** application. For views one **can** use DI, but only to inject the ViewModel (i.e. depending if you are going for View-first or ViewModel-first approach).

On a side note, your `UserControl1ViewModel` violates MVVM as your VM has references to your View, which beats the whole purpose of MVVM

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, it helps more than you could think. I am hust wondering the following. Isn't a view or usercontrol the same thing in principle if it comes to WPF?  To put it simple, all our WPF windows/views are usercontrols in this specific project. And I have a folder called shared where all the usercontrols that is shared in the project resides. So my usercontrol dont need to be used outside the project, therefore I want to link it to a viewmodel where the viewmodel is injected.

Comment: Technically yes, but as I said: View has no logic, so no code behind. A CalendarControl (user control) must draw the calender, handle clicks etc. that is part of code-behind and it exposes DependencyProperties where application specific viewmodels can bind to. In a pure view, there is no need for DPs